# Region of Interest of the fromarray(data)

Tags: python

I am new to python and trying to have some image processing skills on it.

Normally, defining image with cv2, I didn't came across a problem but using below data provides error:

```
 def frame(self):

    read, data = self.camera.read()
    if read:
        cv2.imwrite('char.png', data)
        img = Image.fromarray(data)
        # _, y = img.height
        # _, x = img.width
        # width = int(img.shape[1] )
        # height = int(img.shape[0])

        # img2 = img([width / 2 , height / 3 , width / 3 , height/4])
        # rect_img = image_frame[width / 3[1]: height/3[1], upper_left[0]: bottom_right[0]]
        img.load()
```

I am taking the frame from the webcam and it is located as data file but when I call it, I am not able to process it. What I am trying is to take cropping but it gave the errors:

```
img is not supscriptible
```

or

```
data cannot be divided.
```

How could I take the ROIwith this scenario?

```
def frame(self):
    read, data = self.camera.read()
    if read:
        cv2.imwrite('char.png', data)
        img = Image.fromarray(data)

        # my x0,x1,y0 and y1 are dependent on width and height of the frame.

        img2 = img([width / 2 , height / 3 , width / 3 , height/4])
        rect_img = image_frame[width / 3[1]: height/3[1], upper_left[0]:bottom_right[0]]
        img.load()
```

Comment: Can you share more detail about the errors? I suspect it's because you're trying to slice using `width / 3`, which is a float where it expects an integer. Does it work if you do `width // 3`? If `width` is an integer, why do you need to do `width / 3[1]`?

Comment: I tried width // 3 and this time the error became "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" I have a rectangle there which indicated on the screen. I would like to take the rectangle area. Normally my width, height is 640 480. I have tried directly put 640/3 and 480/3 as well and the error became TypeError: 'Image' object is not callable.

Comment: Use a debugger, add breakpoints, see what the types of each variable are. You're getting confused by Python's lack of strong typing, You can easily crop images by taking slices of the image data array `data` that you read from the camera. All the variables in the slice operation (row start index, length, col start index, length) need to be integers.

Comment: Despite setting them as integer I have the error: AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'shape'

Comment: The error tells you an OpenCV image object has no `.shape` attribute. None of the code you've shared shows you trying to access the `.shape` attribute of any image. You can crop an image by slicing the **array containing its pixel values**. In your example, it would seem you need to slice `data` after `if read:`. I have to ask at this point, _are you reading the errors you get?_ Because it seems like you aren't. The error message usually tells you which line has the error, and contains enough information to figure out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: after checking yhe details you adviced I noticed that I can not assign any attempt after data. I tried to call shape values before calling them but the result did not change. My error always changes but I couldn't pass that line anyway and I still don't know why.So I will try to solve it wit another functions in the whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is solved the issue now I could have the ROI but it takes the int values as you have already indicated. I wonder if there would be a way to take it as float.

```
def frame(self):

    read, data = self.camera.read()
    width, height, pixel = data.shape
    if read:
        self.image_data.emit(data)

    read, data = self.camera.read()
    data = data[(width // 3): (height // 3), (width // 3): (height // 3)]
    # print(data)
    if read:
        cv2.imwrite('ID.png', data)
        img2 = Image.fromarray(data)

        img = img2.copy()

    img.load()
```

Trying to convert width and weight to float, I had the error:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```